# ImportError: cannot import name 'html'

Tags: python-3.4

I run this python code and also import lxml library on windows using this:

```
Path > install setup.py
```

It successfully installed.

The code is:

```
from lxml import html
import requests
page = requests.get('http://econpy.pythonanywhere.com/ex/001.html')
tree = html.fromstring(page.text)

#This will create a list of buyers:
buyers = tree.xpath('//div[@title="buyer-name"]/text()')

#This will create a list of prices
prices = tree.xpath('//span[@class="item-price"]/text()')
print ('Buyers: ', buyers)
print ('Prices: ', prices)
```

But when i run this code the following error occurs:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'html'
```

Answer (score 3):

I have a Mac and am using the Anaconda distribution. When I tried to import HTML, I got an error:

```
>>> from html import HTML
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name HTML
```

I found the problem came from the fact that I had two `html` packages in my `$HOME/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages` directory:

```
drwxr-xr-x    8 user.name  staff     256 Feb  7 12:54 html/
drwxr-xr-x    9 user.name  staff     288 Feb 26 14:15 html-1.16.dist-info/
-rw-r--r--    1 user.name  staff   19209 Feb 26 14:15 html.py
-rw-r--r--    1 user.name  staff   24206 Feb 26 14:15 html.pyc
```

The file `html.py` and the directory `html-1.16.dist-info/` are the correct contents. I don't know how the `html/` directory got there. I deleted `html/', so now I have:

```
drwxr-xr-x    9 user.name  staff     288 Feb 26 14:15 html-1.16.dist-info/
-rw-r--r--    1 user.name  staff   19209 Feb 26 14:15 html.py
-rw-r--r--    1 user.name  staff   24206 Feb 26 14:15 html.pyc
```

The import statement works now:

```
>>> from html import HTML
>>>
```

Comment: Followed the tip. Working well. Thank you.

Comment: I had the same issue on my mac osx. This solution worked really well. if it helps, I had two more files in my `site-packages` directory (`html5lib` and `html5lib-1.0.1.dist-info`) and I deleted them as well to end up with exactly the same three files as mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install html package...Check this url

> https://pypi.python.org/pypi/html/

Comment: do you have two version of python install on your windows?

Comment: Check sys.path to make sure the directory where the module is installed is in there, otherwise you have to add it (google PYTHONPATH windows for some help with that.)

Comment: No only python3.4 version is installed.

Comment: Sorry, this is not an answer! the problem is not about installing the package but using it after installation

Answer (score 0):

try

```
from html import *
```

it worked for me..